# Barcode image storing in local folder not working

Tags: php, barcode

I used barcode generation in my site. When I used it within HTML tags it's working fine.

```
<div class="barcode_img"><img src="<?php echo AT::getUrl(); ?>/barcode/image.php?code=code39&o=1&dpi=150&t=30&r=1&rot=0&text=TEST NAME WITH SPACE&f1=Arial.ttf&f2=10&a1=&a2=&a3=" class="barcode fr"/></div>
```

I need to get that image to store it in local folder called "media/barcode/". For that, I used the code below:

```
$valid_barcodename="testimage";
$barcodeurl = AT::getUrl() . "barcode/image.php?code=code39&o=1&dpi=150&t=30&r=1&rot=0&text=TEST NAME WITH SPACE&f1=Arial.ttf&f2=10&a1=&a2=&a3=";
        $barcode_img = 'media/barcode/testing_' .$valid_barcodename . '.png';
        file_put_contents($barcode_img, file_get_contents($barcodeurl));
```

The image stored in that folder is not empty. When I analyzed it I found, if I give the name "TEST NAME WITH SPACE" without space (TESTNAMEWITHSPACE), it works.

However if I give it with space it won't work. What is the issue?

Note: AT::getUrl() - used for get my base url.

Comment: Look at URLEncoding your 'TEST NAME WITH SPACE' before adding it to the URL, this way it will add + where spaces are, which may fix your problem.

Comment: http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces have special meaning in URLs, so you have to encode them:

```
$text = urlencode("TEST NAME WITH SPACE")
$barcodeurl = AT::getUrl() . "barcode/image.php?code=code39&o=1&dpi=150&t=30&r=1&rot=0&text=". $text ."&f1=Arial.ttf&f2=10&a1=&a2=&a3=";
```

In the above code, `$text` now contains your text, encoded and ready to be used in your URL (you will notice the spaces have been replaced with `%20` codes).

Answer (score 1):

> Note: If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces,
>   you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents

Alternatively, you can use cURL if enabled on your server.

```
function curl($url, $setopt = array(), $post = array())
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    if( ! empty($post))
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if( ! empty($setopt))
    {
        foreach($setopt as $key => $value)
        {
            curl_setopt($curl, constant($key), $value);   
        }
    }
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

Usage:

```
file_put_contents($barcode_img, curl($barcodeurl));
```